# LWP HTTPS proxy timing out

Tags: perl, https, proxy, lwp

I am trying to connect via HTTPS to a site using LWP::Simple.  I have set the environment variables both inside of the script and in the shell.  I continue to get a 500 Connection Timed Out.  I can connect to a HTTP site just fine.

The proxy is letting communication through.  I can connect to the HTTPS site through the proxy using curl without a problem.

Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; 
use Net::SSL;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Debug qw(+);
use Data::Dumper;

$ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS} = "Net::SSL";
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
$ENV{HTTPS_VERSION} = 2;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new (verify_hostname => 0);
$ua->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0,
                SSL_verify_mode => 0x00);       
$ua->proxy('https' => 'http://x.x.x.x:3128');

print $ua->proxy('https');
print Dumper($ua);
my $response = $ua->get('https://qualys.com/');
print Dumper ($response);
if ($response->is_success) {
     print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
     exit(0);
}
else {
 print "\nFail:\n";
     print $response->status_line ."\n";
     exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS proxy support for [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) is (or at least was until some days ago) broken, at least if you use [`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL), which is the default for LWP versions >=6.0 because it provides better security. It should be much better now with LWP 6.0.6 and [`LWP::Protocol::https`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3ahttps) 6.0.6 which were released few days ago. If you cannot upgrade you might try using [`Net::SSLGlue::LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSLGlue%3a%3aLWP) which patches LWP for better https proxy support.